# Feign client on Java - extract required data from json

Tags: java, json, feign

I am new in Fiegn. I need to extract list of gif url from this response - https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=WXpCt1X1tDwup2N1YRcBqfI38edEvweb&q=rich.
I dont need main part of data, i want convert this to list of gif url. How to do it?

My response:
https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=WXpCt1X1tDwup2N1YRcBqfI38edEvweb&q=rich

need to get:
list of gif url
Path - data - images - origin - url

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this task by creating models for all objects in the response https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=WXpCt1X1tDwup2N1YRcBqfI38edEvweb&q=rich. Feign automatically parsing json in POJO